# Movie with a girl imprisoned by a psychiatrist

Tags: story-identification, movie

Years ago - probably 5-10 - I saw a trailer for a movie that was being made which was very stunning.

It was about a girl who was forced by a psychiatrist to live in a single room her entire life, her only outward connection in life is his psychological experiments. It had an amazing 70s visual design, and some of the sets reminded me of the spaceship scenes in *2001: A Space Odyssey*. I believe it was a foreign film - I thought it might be Australian.

Regardless, I never did hear of it again when it came out and have been dying to locate it to watch it, it looked amazing.

Comment: But... was it SF?

Comment: Or was it fantasy?

Comment: @bazz You don't get many stories like that in a fantasy setting.

Comment: It wasn't [Beyond The Black Rainbow](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1534085/) by any chance? I'm not sure it completely fits your description but there are definite parallels!

Answer (score 6):

I may be completely wrong but it could be *[Beyond The Black Rainbow](http://www.imdb.co.uk/title/tt1534085/)*

The general gist of it is that a girl is imprisoned not by her psychiatrist, but by a scientist. She's in a specialized medial facility and has special "abilities" - she is heavily sedated but tries to escape.

Check it out - I could be very wrong but it could be! :)